# How do I solve this layout with CSS in Ionic / Vue.Js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, ionic-framework

I’m currently trying to wrap my head around solving this layout with Ionic and CSS:

[image]

This is the result I achieve even after spending quite some time with it:

[image]

I've recreated the basic setup on the home page: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dwp2fw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

The layout consists of a navbar, a fullscreen image and text-content below that. The gradient is constructed using a ::after attribute in CSS as I don't want to hard embedd the gradient in the image file with Photoshop and the likes.  I had to construct the fullscreen image using a ‚position:absolute‘ attribute:

```
.happening-image {
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position:absolute; }
```

because for reasons beyond my knowledge, not using ‚position:absolute’ results in the image not being displayed in fullscreen but being 2 or 3 pixels smaller than the total width and thus leaving a slim border of background color around the image:

[image]

Once I do use the ‚position:absolute’ attribute however my layout becomes a complete mess because the text content is being placed all over the image content.

[image]

This is where I'm struggling to come up with a solution that tidly places the text content below the fullscreen image. Using padding is, to my understanding, not possible as quick fix as I need the layout to be independent from the image content:

[image]

if I use padding based on the height of portrait sized images, the content gets too much offset when for landscape sized images and vice versa. *I could try to target landscape and portrait images using different .css classes for each and setting and matching padding, I do however feel that using padding is not the best solution.*

**Can someone point me to my error or a robust, content-independent solution here that keeps Image and text content tidly in order while maintaining the layout?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dwp2fw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss), the border around the image is happening because of the **padding** attribute in the **ion-content tag**, here:

[image]

If you remove that **padding** the image will have no space around.

By the way, the `position:absolute;` did the trick, because it makes the image get out of the page flow, and so, it acted as a child of the body, which doesn't have any padding/margin around.

**Edited**

Also, you need to remove the `position:absolute` from your image and add `padding:0;` to the tag above it, as it is adding a little space around from padding.

[image]

And from what I understood, the image and text will behave as you wished.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer and the enlightenment on how 'position:absolute;' did the trick.

The padding attribute is the result of a copy + paste error, the actual tag is

<ion-content fullscreen no-padding>

If I remove this 'no-padding'  the navigation will not be transparent anymore and the text content will still overlap the image.

Comment: No problem mate, take a look at the second part of the answer, and check if it resolves your problem.